# Vue.js animate page transitions with javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, transition, vue-router

I have a simple vue app with 3 routes using vue-router package. Lets say homepage has 3 big square columns, about one big text block and contact a form with 4 form rows.

When I use the default `<transition/>` element around my `<router-view/>` element it fades in- and out nicely, but I want specific animations for each route. Homepage should stagger the 3 blocks, about should fade-in-from-top the big text block and contact should stagger the form fields.

How do I go about this?
I tried working with javascript hooks (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#JavaScript-Hooks) but I cant get to make it work.

routes.js

```
import home from './components/Home.vue';
import about from './components/About.vue';
import contact from './components/Contact.vue';

export default [
{ path: '/',        component: home },
{ path: '/about',   component: about },
{ path: '/contact', component: contact }
];
```

App.vue

```
<template>
    <router-view></router-view>
 </template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Home.js

```
<template>
  <transition>
    <div id="intro">
      <div class="columns">
        <div class="column">
          Column 1
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          Column 2
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          Column 3
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </transition>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
    }
  },
  methods: {
    beforeEnter: function (el) {
      alert('before');
    }
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

I hoped the beforeEnter method would've worked but that is not the case...

Answer (score 2):

In your components add :

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
    next(vm=>{
        vm.enter()
    })
},
beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {
    this.leave(next)
},
methods:{
    enter(){
        console.log('animation in')
    },
    leave(done){
        console.log('animation out, onComplete:done()')
        done()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the documentation for [`vue-router`'s transitions](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/transitions.html).  The documentation suggest that you add a `watch` to the scope that is visible to the `<transition>` so that you can change your `name` attribute.

For example:

```js
const Home = {
  name: "Home",
  template: "<div class='view'>I'm Home</div>"
};

const Foo = {
  name: "Foo",
  template: "<div class='view'>I'm Foo</div>"
};

const Bar = {
  name: "Bar",
  template: "<div class='view'>I'm Bar</div>"
};

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [{
    name: "Home",
    path: "/",
    component: Home
  }, {
    name: "Foo",
    path: "/foo",
    component: Foo
  }, {
    name: "Bar",
    path: "/bar",
    component: Bar
  }]
});

const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  router,
  data() {
    return {
      transitionToUse: "spin"
    };
  },
  watch: {
    $route(to, from) {
      switch (to.name) {
        case "Foo":
          this.transitionToUse = "fade";
          break;
        case "Bar":
          this.transitionToUse = "spin";
          break;
        default:
          this.transitionToUse = "grow";
          break;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
main {
  text-align: center;
}

.view {
  display: inline-block;
}


/*fade transition*/

.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .5s;
}

.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}


/*spin transition*/

.spin-enter-active,
.spin-leave-active {
  transition: transform .5s;
}

.spin-enter,
.spin-leave-to {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}


/*grow transition*/

.grow-enter-active,
.grow-leave-active {
  transition: transform .5s;
}

.grow-enter,
.grow-leave-to {
  transform: scale(4);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@2.0.0/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <router-link to="/">Home</router-link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <router-link to="/foo">Foo</router-link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <router-link to="/bar">Bar</router-link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <h1></h1>
    <transition :name="transitionToUse" mode="out-in">
      <router-view></router-view>
    </transition>
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm looking for a javascript implementation, no css animations since I want to complete controll in JS about state and stuff.. I want to stagger elements, ...

Answer (score 0):

if i understood u right, u have want something like that:

In your App.vue:

```
<template>
  <transition :name='transitionName'>
    <router-view ></router-view>
  </transition>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    transitionName: 'transitionHome'
  }),
  watch: {
    '$route' (to, from) {
      const contact = to.path === '/contact' ? true : false
      const home =  to.path === '/' ? true : false
      const about =  to.path === '/about' ? true : false
      if (contact === true) {
        this.transitionName = 'transitionContact'
      } else if (about === true) {
        this.transitionName = 'transitionAbout'
      } else {
        this.transitionName = 'transitionHome'
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Well, maybe it is not the best solution.

Comment: This too would apply to css animations, I'm looking to control animation with javascript..

Comment: @frederikvdbe did you find any solutions?

Comment: @besrabasant I used nuxt.js instead, nuxt is great!